# iPython notebook "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ipython

I am working from this Kaggle notebook :

https://www.kaggle.com/kitakoj18/exploring-wine-descriptions-with-nlp-and-kmeans

Please see in [15] section where the notebook is trying to run :

```
variety_df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
```

This results in the error message :

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

How can this be fixed? I can't make sense of it from the docs.

Thank you.

Comment: How is created `variety_df` ? Maybe need `.copy()` like `variety_df = df[df.A == 1].copy()`

Comment: this is not an error but a warning, and agree with @jezrael, looks like `variety_df` is a view of a dataframe, not a dataframe on its own